# Stack overflow (параметры: 0x00000001, 0x00242FFC)

Tags: c++, память, рекурсия, стек

Собственно, на stackoverflow иронично прихожу с одноименной проблемой.

Задумывался брудфорс пароля (последовательности символов).
Не могу понять в чем беда: либо дело в моих кривых рекурсиях, либо же слишком многого требую от программы (недостаточно ресурсов).

Пароль подбирался изначально по всей кодировке, но для поиска проблемы укоротил до трех символов: 'a', 'b', и 'c'.

Суть программы заключается в том, что циклом она перебирает только последний элемент пароля, а все, что стоят раньше чем он изменяются в ф-ии "up_level(int, const char*, char*, int)".

Файл с функциями:

```
//  ipnut: пароль, найденный пароль, длина пароля
//  output: логическое "да" - найден и "нет" в противном случае
bool search(const char* pswd, char* solved_pswd, int length) {

    // подстановка всех возможных символов на последнюю позицию пароля
    for (int runner(97); runner < 100; runner++) {

        solved_pswd[length - 1] = (char)runner;

        if (!strcmp(solved_pswd, pswd)) // выход при нахождении совпадения
            return 1;
    }

    if (up_level(1, pswd, solved_pswd, length)) // переход к изменению предшествующих символов 
        search(pswd, solved_pswd, length);      // переход к перебору последнего символа с измененными
                                                // предшествующими
    // выход, если не удалось подобрать
    else
        return 0;
}

//  input: сдвиг с конца, пароль, найденный пароль, длина
//  output: логическое "нет" в случае, когда испробованы все варианты
 bool up_level(int offset, const char* pswd, char* cur_pswd, int length) {

    // проверка выхода за пределы строки
    if (offset > length - 1)
        return 0;

    // проверка символа (точно не последнего), на его равенство крайнему возможному варианту
    if (cur_pswd[length - offset - 1] == (char)99) {

        cur_pswd[length - offset - 1] = (char)97;   // заменяем проверенный символ на минимальный возможный
        up_level(++offset, pswd, cur_pswd, length); // и переходим к символу на единицу ближе к началу
    }

    // увеличение символа на 1 и возвращение к перебору
    ++cur_pswd[length - offset - 1];

    return 1;
}
```

// Файл с мейном:

```
void main() {

    int length_of_pswd; // для длинны пароля
    string string_pswd; // для считывания строки произвольной длины

    cout << "input ur pswd: ";
    cin >> string_pswd;

    length_of_pswd = string_pswd.length();

    char* users_pswd = new char[length_of_pswd];    // введенный пароль
    char* solve_pswd = new char[length_of_pswd];    // будущий найденный пароль

    strcpy(users_pswd, string_pswd.c_str());

    // begin
    // заполнение символами 'a'
    for (int runner(0); runner < length_of_pswd; runner++)
        solve_pswd[runner] = (char)97;

    solve_pswd[length_of_pswd] = '\0';  // дополнение нулевым байтом
    // end

    // подбор пароля
    if (search(users_pswd, solve_pswd, length_of_pswd)) {

        system("cls");
        cout << "\n\n\tthank's for waiting =)\nI know ur passwod is: " << solve_pswd << "\n\n\n";
    }

    else 
        cout << "\tthank's for waiting =)\nu've got best password I've ever seen ;)\n";

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос тег использованного языка - `C++`. Тогда, глядишь, кто и поможет...

Comment: из функции `search` вы не возвращаете результат, что приводит к неопределённому поведению. поможет команда `return` : `if (up_level(1, pswd, solved_pswd, length)) return search(pswd, solved_pswd, length);`

Answer (score 0):

В участке кода:

```
    if (up_level(1, pswd, solved_pswd, length)) // переход к изменению предшествующих символов 
    search(pswd, solved_pswd, length);
```

Вы всегда как offset подаете `1`, а значит и рекурсия, что под условием, становиться бесконечной и забивает stack, ибо 1 не увеличивается и не становится больше чем `length`, а значит и условие никогда не станет ложью.

Кажется, проблема в этом.